# Django. settings.py -> STATIC_ROOT/STATICFILES_DIRS

Tags: python, django, static, root

Have a problem with connecting css to my template. 
My project root is 
`"D:/birzha/", static path is "D:/birzha/static/"`, `css` in

`"D:/birzha/static/css/template.css"`.

What `STATIC_ROOT` or `STATICFILES_DIRS` should I use for correctly viewing css file? I tried so much turns, but nothing happens, css still off.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to tell where all your static files will be "collected", place the following lines in `settings.py`:

```
BASE_DIR = (os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Then you need to make a `static` folder within your `app` and the hierarchy
    should be like this `appname/static/appname/css`.
Finally run the command `python manage.py collectstatic` and type `yes` on prompt. This will copy all of your static files within a folder that you specified in `STATIC_ROOT`

Now you can access your static files by giving the path like,`/static/appname/css/mystyle.css`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this 
Site root will contain you project root path. You can change "/templates" with static

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


# calculated paths for django and the site
# used as starting points for various other paths

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates/'),
)


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates/media/')

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'templates/'),
)
```